# Algorithm to fix binary search tree

Tags: algorithm

Any ideas how to fix binary search tree after subtracting a constant from every node on a random path from the root to a leaf?

Comment: Write a balancing function that is called on the update of the nodes. You can probably do it just at the end to save on computation costs. Example [here.](https://adrianmejia.com/blog/2018/07/16/self-balanced-binary-search-trees-with-avl-tree-data-structure-for-beginners/)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It sounds like you have an X-Y problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: I would rather read each element from the tree, subtract the constant and insert into a new binary search tree while balancing it and then destroy the original ( if possible ).